# Is there an official logo of C#?

Tags: c#

I'm currently working on a presentation that involves C# (and .NET). Is there some kind of official logo of the programming language? If so, do you know of a free image source? I tried google but to no avail.

Comment: There is now a uservoice suggestion for that:
https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/7089021-provide-official-logos-for-the-net-languages

Comment: You're free to use the purple C# logo btw https://chrismckee.co.uk/c-logo-for-stuff-and-stickers/
I basically recreated the C++ one years ago to contain the # and use VS colours at the time; Microsoft helped themselves to it so I made it clear the licence is go nuts 

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know of an official logo for the C# language, however, there is a logo for the general "world" of .NET.

The current .NET logo is:

[image]

This was introduced sometime around the end of 2008.  Here's the blog post from Microsoft's Scott Hanselman that details this:

[PDC 2008: New .NET Logo](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PDC2008NewNETLogo.aspx)

However, regarding using the logo *yourself*, please see this Stack Overflow question (and specifically the accepted answer):

[Can I use the .NET framework logo on my personal calling card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617531/can-i-use-the-net-framework-logo-on-my-personal-calling-card)

In short, the answer is No.   :(

Comment: Still no C# logo, but as of 2020 there is a repo for .NET logo on [brand repository](https://github.com/dotnet/brand) on the GitHub. Make sure the logo usage is compliant to the brand guidelines.

Answer (score 10):

There kinda was once... [Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339640/why-was-the-c-mascot-andy-retired):

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Not for C#, but certainly for .NET

[alt text http://www.microsoft.com/net/images/net-logo.jpg](http://www.microsoft.com/net/images/net-logo.jpg)

If you're really after something to represent C# specifically then you could grab the .cs file icon that's used in Windows Explorer once Visual Studio has been installed.

If you're presenting on the 3.0 additions to the .NET framework then you might find the following graphic useful (it does, however use the old (pre-2008) .NET logo)

[image]
<sub>(source: [dnzone.com](http://www.dnzone.com/downloads/images/framework3_1.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 3):

i dont think if there is an official logo. if there was such a logo, all the books of c# would have it.

Answer (score 1):

**Visual C#** is a Microsoft implementation of a programming language called [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language)) (which is again, created by Microsoft which is approved as a standard by ISO and Ecma )

As others suggested, there is no specific logo for C#, may be go with **.NET logo** or something like this: [alt text http://www.technologysolutionsgrove.com/tips/images/VisualCSharp2005Logo.jpg](http://www.technologysolutionsgrove.com/tips/images/VisualCSharp2005Logo.jpg)

Btw, beware of copyright issues.

Answer (score 1):

The closest would be the Visual C# 2010 Express logo, which at least is officially by Microsoft and has "csharp_logo" in it's name
[image: Microsoft's Visual C# 2010 Express logo]

see:
http://www.microsoft.com/germany/express/products/assets/images/csharp_logo.png

Comment: I'm not clear about the legalese at 
http://www.microsoft.com/about/legal/en/us/IntellectualProperty/Trademarks/Usage/General.aspx

But I am surely interested to know whether Microsoft has to pay the x Billion EUR fine it might have to pay since it did not follow the orders of the EU commission.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be very careful with the branding stuff from Microsoft, they are really restrictive as to what you are allowed to do with their logos.

If it's for marketing, I think you would be best looking for the certified for windows, server, sql server brandings, these mean more in the marketplace and MS are good about you getting them.